# Parse's CurrentUser doesn't keep refreshed data

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Using Parse for iOS, I modified the _User's table to have a field called "Friends" which is an array of pointers to other _Users (by the way, I also have other additional fields).

When I call `PFUser.currentUser()`, I don't see this friends field in the user object. So I call `PFUser.currentUser().fetch()` (because `refresh` method doesn't seem to exist anymore) and I finally have the `friends` field in my currentUser object.

However, as soon as I exit the app, this field is lost. It doesn't seem to be saved locally unlike all the other fields of the current user.

How am I supposed to force a refresh of the cached current user ?

Answer (score 1):

According to parse.com itself and [one of their posts](https://parse.com/questions/when-you-modify-a-pfuser-does-it-write-through-the-authenticated-user-cache), there is no other way to keep your user up-to-date:

> `saveEventually` does not write through any caches at this time,
>   including the `currentUser`, if the app has been restarted. You'll need
>   to regularly call fetch to keep it up-to-date. We are aware that this
>   is inconvenient, and are looking into ways to make it work better for
>   you.

Comment: That post is from 2 years ago and they mentioned that they will look into it. Still no news ? Do I have to fetch at every launch ?

Comment: I know. But there is no new information about any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you want your user objects to contain a value that's an array like that? I obviously don't know your use application, but I would recommend using a PFRelation instead. It works just like an array, but the Parse Framework provides a bunch of additional functionality along with it.

As for your specific question it might have to deal with Parse. Maybe they don't automatically retrieve and save arrays that are on an object. That would be my guess because an array could contain who knows how much data in it. I still don't know why they wouldn't locally save that data after it's fetched.

My suggestion is probably a little over the top, but would most likely be the best outcome. Utilize a local database such as CoreData or even the ParseLocalDatastore. Then encapsulate the Parse framework to have your own User object where you can store the information, which can also maintain persistence via your database.

Comment: I want to use an array to keep things very simple. I don't need to query the relations, I just need to query the user and get all his fields. And I believe the queries are faster this way.

Comment: By the way, is there a possible way to use the Parse local database (introduced a few months ago) ? If I fetch current User do I need to pin it ?

Comment: Right. I totally understand what you're looking for by querying the User, but I'm just not sure if they provide that functionality without fetching first. If you are required to fetch it then I can't see why you wouldn't want to use a PFRelation, especially if you're storing the data locally in a db. The time to fetch the array off the user vs the time to query the relation would be nearly identical.  Plus it'll let you create custom queries to find specific objects inside the friends relation. You could use the PLD to fetch and pin a user. Then you can just retrieve the info from the DB.